# How to sample the probability of events on a grid?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to model the probability of $\mathbf{e}$ identical events to distribute over a grid with $\mathbf{n}$ different cells. The fundamental assumption I want to model is that each cell in the grid has the same probability to get an event. Threfore, I started modelling the sample space $(\Omega)$ for a trivial example $\mathbf{e}=4$, $\mathbf{n}=4$ on paper using basic counting as follows:

$$ |\Omega| = \sum_{\lambda \in {\pmb{P}_{(e,n)}^*}} \mathbf{D}(n, |\lambda|) \cdot {1 \over \prod_{i \in r_{\lambda}} !i} $$
where $\pmb{P}_{(e,n)}^*$ is the set containing all the integer partitions of $\mathbf{e}$ whose elements have a number of terms lower or equal to $\mathbf{n}$ and $r_{\lambda}$ is a set containing the number of repetitions for repeated terms in $\lambda$. Just to clarify a bit in my toy example $\pmb{P}_{(4,4)}^*=\pmb{P}_4=\{(4,), (1, 3), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2)\}$
and for a given $\lambda$, lets say $\lambda^* = \{2, 1, 1\}$, we have $|\lambda^*|=3$, $r_{\lambda^*}=\{2\}$. Basing on this, I identified the 35 states in the table below:

$$ 
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Sample configuration s} & \text{Number of possible dispositions} \\ 
\hline
   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
        4 & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
   \end{array} & 4 \\
\hline
   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
        3 & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
   \end{array} & 6 \\
\hline
   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
        2 & 2  & 0  & 0 \\
   \end{array} & 12 \\
\hline
   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
        2 & 1  &  1 & 0 \\
   \end{array} & 12 \\
\hline
   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
        1 & 1  &  1 & 1 \\
   \end{array} & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

According to this model I was expecting to have the probability to observe 4 events in the same cell equal to 4/35 and so on for the other arrangements.
On the contrary,  when I tried to simulate the model with a simple program, I found that the results were not in agreement. I noticed that the difference is due to the fact that I used a random number generator to create vectors of indexes of length 4 with values sampled in the interval $I=[1,4]$, consequently the space I am sampling, lets call it $\Omega^*$, is bigger ($|\Omega^*|=256$) and there are many ways to generate the same state in $\Omega$ from a sequence of indexes sampled from $\Omega^*$, i.e. state $  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline 1 & 1  &  1 & 1 \\ \end{array}$ can be generated by the 24 permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$; since indexes in $\Omega^*$ do not distribute uniformly over states in $\Omega$ and both samplings seem to satisfy the requirement for uniform probability of events over cells, the question is: is it my model wrong or my sampling strategy biased or both?

Comment: Edited because there was mistake in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each event is *independently* distributed to one of the $n$ cells in the grid, then your program is correct and your model is wrong. Not all of the partitions are equally likely. Partitions in which the events are evenly distributed, such as $(1,1,1,1)$, are much more probable than very uneven distributions, such as $(4,0,0,0)$ or $(0,4,0,0)$.

You could *declare* that your model is what you want to see. Both the partition model and the independent-choices model have the property that each cell is equally likely to get events.

However, I can't think of any applications in which the uniformly chosen ordered partition model would be reasonable.

If the events are independent, then the probability of an outcome $(e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n)$ (by which I mean that there are $e_i$ events in the $i^{\text{th}}$ cell is) is $$\frac{e!}{e_1!\,e_2!\dots e_n!} \cdot \frac1{n^e}.$$

Comment: Hi Misha, thank you very much for your answer, this leads me to the next question, is there any closed formula or approximation to get the probability of each of the five sample configurations for the case of independently distributed events that does not rely on generating $\Omega^*$?

Comment: I worked it out adding a multiplicative term $ \mathbf{D} (n,|\lambda|)/max(\lambda)$ but I am not sure of the meaning of it.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Misha!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean each unique distribution is equally likely, the model is correct while the program is not.

The program underestimate the probability of having all $4$ events in a cell.